# How can I shorten the regex expression here?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex to check that the special characters don't repeat more than 3 times.

**Regex**:

```
specialChar: /(!){3,}|(@){3,}|(#){3,}|(\$){3,}|(%){3,}|(\^){3,}|(&){3,}|(\*){3,}|(\?){3,}|(_){3,}|(~){3,}/g.test(text),
```

Is there a possible way of shortening the above regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten it using a character class listing all the characters inside a capture group and a backreference, and repeat the backreference 2 or more times.

```
([!@#$%^&*?_~])\1{2,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifbejd/1)